# Redirect to previous page after login

Tags: jquery, vb.net, redirect, session-timeout

I have a redirect to login page (on client side) after session timeout . Can I have redirect the user to the page where he was? Its impossible? Using classic ASP, JS, Jquery ?

Comment: are you using forms authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the latest known page in your database and on login you could redirect the user to that page. You could add checks that if he has been logged off for more than 4 hours he should be redirected to the home page else redirect him to where he was most recently.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET you can use `Request.UrlReferrer` to get the previous page url.
So you can store it somewhere, database or simply store it in a session.
Then after the log-in process you can move back to the stored URL.